# how i stop orientation in Android device?

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

i make a application on Titanium. whose work on cross platform (android or iphone). 
i want to stop orientation in android device how i can do? 
because, android have default orientation change. and iphone have not default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any kind of android application you can use below in android manifest.

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:name="org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"/>
```

For any kind of IOS application you can use below in main plist file in xcode

```
<key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

For Titanium Mobile specific; please check below link from Titanium dev center
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/22241/is-there-a-way-to-disable-orientation-change-on-the-ipadiphone

Answer (score 3):

```
win.orientationModes = [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT];
```

This is working ...